# How can I edit my sequence so it returns one element only using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, linq

I have the code shown below:

```
var subcategories = new List<Subcategory>
{
    new Subcategory { SubcategoryName = "Football", CategoryID = categories.Single(c => c.CategoryName == "Sport").CategoryID },
    new Subcategory { SubcategoryName = "Basketball", CategoryID = categories.Single(c => c.CategoryName == "Sport").CategoryID },
    new Subcategory { SubcategoryName = "Piano", CategoryID = categories.Single(c => c.CategoryName == "Music").CategoryID },
    new Subcategory { SubcategoryName = "Violin", CategoryID = categories.Single(c => c.CategoryName == "Music").CategoryID }
};

foreach (Subcategory s in subcategories)
{
    var subcategoriesInDB = context.Subcategories.Where(c => c.Category.CategoryID == s.CategoryID).SingleOrDefault();

    if (subcategoriesInDB == null)
    {
        context.Subcategories.Add(s);
    }
}
```

The point is that, the query inside the foreach statement returns two elements in my case. Because as you can see I have two subcategories for my two categories, therefore there are total of four subcategories. This causes an error message: `Sequence contains more than one element` when I try the `Update-Database` command.

As you can see my Subcategory names are all different, therefore I want to add also a check for that. So, if the category ids are the same, then we will check whether the subcategory names are different then the ones already existing inside the database, so it will either return one entry or null. If someone can help me achieve it, or give me another solution I would be glad.

**Update:**

If I change it to:

```
var subcategoriesInDB = context.Subcategories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Category.CategoryID == s.CategoryID);
```

And then do a Update-Database command, I get a new error message saying:

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception
>   for details.

Comment: As I said (below), you'll need to provide a code example of you "doing a updata-database command". That'll be a different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 var subcategoriesInDB = context.Subcategories.Where(c => c.Category.CategoryID == s.CategoryID).SingleOrDefault();
```

Should read....

```
 var subcategoriesInDB = context.Subcategories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Category.CategoryID == s.CategoryID);
```

In using `SingleOrDefault` you're implying only one element will be returned. If there are none, you'll get `null`, if there are more than one, you'll get an exception to let you know there are multiple (i.e. not what you expected). The use of `FirstOrDefault` implies you are aware there may be multiple elements that match your query, but you only want the first.

Comment: When I change it to FirstOrDefault, and do the Update-Database command, I get an error message saying: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: That's probably because now you're code's getting past the exception, so you're seeing an error more closely related to what you're actually trying to achieve (a little bit further on). That's a different question I'm afraid.

Comment: Regardless of where you put the predicate (`Where`, `FirstOrDefault`), the generated query will be the same

Comment: Ah right, I stand corrected. Think I was getting confused with calling `ToList()` before taking what you need.